# how to check $_post variable in foreach loop with multiple arrays

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, isset

I am using this code to filter multiple fields

```
$fields = array('ageid', 'heightid', 'waistid'); //database fields
    $txtfields = array('txtagefrom', 'txtheightfrom', 'txtwaistfrom'); //from range
    $txttofields = array('txtageto', 'txtheightto', 'txtwaistto'); // To Range


$conditions = array();
foreach (array_map(NULL, $fields, $txtfields, $txttofields) as $x) {

  list($fields, $txtfields, $txttofields) = $x;
 echo "'" . $fields . "' between '" . $txtfields . "' And '" . $txttofields . "'";
}
```

but I am stuck, if some fields are empty then also it shows on result, I tried multiple methods but failed.

I need, if any of these fields are empty, then it won't show on the result.

See the full code [here](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ijn4-usx0)

Comment: `if(empty($var)){ do something }`

Comment: if (!empty($var)) { do_something(); } you mean?

Comment: Can you show the part where you `filter multiple fields`?

Comment: `echo (!emtpy($var)) ? $var : 'this var is empty'`

Comment: `if(count($x) === 3)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the $fields is empty or is_null
Also there is a typo in your code

```
<input type="text" name="txtwasitto" placeholder="Wasit To" />
```

Change it to

```
<input type="text" name="txtwaistto" placeholder="Wasit To" />
```

make sure you remove XSS from $_POST

```
$fields = array('ageid', null, 'heightid', null, 'waistid'); //database fields
$txtfields = array('txtagefrom', 'testnull', 'txtheightfrom', 'testnull', 'txtwaistfrom'); //from range
$txttofields = array('txtageto', 'testnull', 'txtheightto', 'testnull', 'txtwaistto'); // To Range

$conditions = array();
foreach (array_map(NULL, $fields, $txtfields, $txttofields) as $x) {
    list($fields, $txtfields, $txttofields) = $x;
    if(!empty($_POST[$txtfields]) && !empty($_POST[$txttofields]))
    echo "'" . $fields . "' between '" . $_POST[$txtfields] . "' And '" . $_POST[$txttofields] . "'";
}
```

Comment: @pawan35 i am not seeing any null in the result ( 'ageid' between 'txtagefrom' And 'txtageto''heightid' between 'txtheightfrom' And 'txtheightto''waistid' between 'txtwaistfrom' And 'txtwaistto') what are you expecting?

Comment: I will tell you in brief. I am creating a modeling agency portal, where any user can search models with range vise for e.g. Age: From 20 To 30 Or Height Or Waist.
But If any User want to search only with Age and height, but not with Waist. then this code won't work properly.

Check this.
http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ijn4-usx0

Comment: @pawan35 see the updated answer this will give you the result you are looking for.

Comment: @pawan35 ur welcome, peer review the update to the question so others can benefit looking at the complete question.